# Run build in teamcity for a specific branch

Tags: continuous-integration, teamcity

I've come from a Bamboo build server, and I'm trying out TeamCity for my project. The one thing I like about Bamboo is that branches are treated like first class citizens, where as in TeamCity they kind of feel like an afterthought.

What I'm trying to achieve is have one build configuration, and then use that same build configuration across multiple branches to build artifacts.

I've got the following settings in my VCS Root settings for my build configuration:

[image: Branch specification]

What I'm expecting from this is that 'develop' is my default branch, and then any 'release' branches (i.e. release/Release_1.0.0 or release/Release_1.1.0) are also selected and built against.

However, when I try to build a specific branch, I get an empty list in the 'Run...' option for branches:

[image: Empty branch list]

Is anyone able to help explain what's going on here? I've read the following information https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD10/Working+with+Feature+Branches however that page seems to indicate it should just work, however it's not.

What I'd like to be able to do is also create configurations per branch, where I can override parameters for the branches, but not have to duplicate build configurations.

Answer (score 0):

TeamCity works with branches, but in your case, I think it takes only active branches.
Branches which are `active` have recent commits on them.

And, as far as I know, it is not possible to override parameters for specific branches.